# SQLite error Insufficient parameters supplied to the command vb.net

Tags: vb.net, sqlite

salam i get this error(SQLite error Insufficient parameters supplied to the command) in this code please help me

```
 If CheckBox1.Checked Then
            Dim query1 As String = "Select payid FROM SS_paymon WHERE paytid = '" & idtext.Text & "'"

            Dim command As New SQLiteCommand(query1, objConn)
            'Dim param As New SQLiteParameter()
            Dim haha As DataTable = New DataTable()
            Dim adapter As New SQLiteDataAdapter(command)
            adapter.Fill(haha)
            If haha.Rows.Count = 0 Then
                Dim SQLstr3 As String = "INSERT INTO SS_paymon (payprice, paybuyer, paydate,paytid) VALUES(@payprice, @paybuyer, @paydate,@paytid)"
                Dim cmdb3 As New SQLiteCommand(SQLstr2, objConn)
                cmdb3.Parameters.AddWithValue("@payprice", TextBox5.Text)
                cmdb3.Parameters.AddWithValue("@paybuyer", bid.Text)
                cmdb3.Parameters.AddWithValue("@paydate", TextBox4.Text)
                cmdb3.Parameters.AddWithValue("@paytid", idtext.Text)
                cmdb3.ExecuteNonQuery()
                cmdb3.Dispose()
            Else
                Dim SQLstr3 As String = "UPDATE SS_paymon SET payprice=@payprice, paybuyer=@paybuyer, paydate=@paydate WHERE paytid=@paydate"
                Dim cmd3 As New SQLiteCommand(SQLstr2, objConn)
                cmd3.Parameters.AddWithValue("@payprice", TextBox5.Text)
                cmd3.Parameters.AddWithValue("@paybuyer", bid.Text)
                cmd3.Parameters.AddWithValue("@paydate", TextBox4.Text)
                cmd3.Parameters.AddWithValue("@paytid", idtext.Text)
                cmd3.ExecuteNonQuery()
                cmd3.Dispose()
            End If
            adapter.Dispose()
        Else
            Dim query1 As String = "Select payid FROM SS_paymon WHERE paytid = '" & idtext.Text & "'"
            Dim command As New SQLiteCommand(query1, objConn)
            Dim haha As DataTable = New DataTable()
            Dim adapter As New SQLiteDataAdapter(command)
            adapter.Fill(haha)
            If haha.Rows.Count <> 0 Then
                Dim SQLstr3 As String = "DELETE FROM SS_paymon where paytid=@paytid"
                Dim cmdx1 As New SQLiteCommand(SQLstr2, objConn)
                cmdx1.Parameters.AddWithValue("@paytid", idtext.Text)
                cmdx1.ExecuteNonQuery()
                cmdx1.Dispose()
            End If

        End If
```

i get this error in all ExecuteNonQuery().

is there any problem i searchedbut i could not find anything for this code

it's a update button;
if check box (PAID) is checked it should check if any record from payment table
if it has something so update it else add new one
if check not checked it's should check if any record exist for the payment it should delete it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The string variables that you set in this code are named `SQLstr3`.
The string variable that you actually use in the commands is named `SQLstr2`.

And `WHERE paytid=@paydate` is wrong.